# A question about categorical features using pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a little perplexity about categorical variables in pandas.

My question is, if I have already managed to expand the features that I need in my `df` in the following way

```
cat1     cat2      cat3
 0        0          1
 1        0          0
 0        0          1
 ..       ..         ..
```

where `df['cat1'].dtype` is `int64` (same for others), will they be automatically considered as categorical features by running some machine learning algorithm? Or do I need to perform some transformations on them to be treated specifically as categories?

Comment: You need some transformation and also explanation for you question ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers / one hot encoded variables are the norm for non-ordinal categorical features. You've got exactly what you need as input for most models.